# Unlimited scrollback on command line

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-lite

So, I decided to clean the dust off my RPi and put it to good use, so I installed Raspbian Stretch Lite (no desktop) and while doing some initial config stuff, I notice I couldn't scrollback more than half a "page". I did my research but couldn't find any solution that would work. So basically, how do I set the command line so it lets me scroll back 1000 or 2000 or 10000 lines?

Comment: You are using `LXTerminal`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Lite, but it sounds like this is the same situation as when I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a pure console session on full Raspbian Stretch. That is, by default I cannot scroll up more than a full screen at 1080p resolution.

For me, it worked when I resolved this by editing /boot/cmdline.txt and appending `fbcon=scrollback:1024k`

After rebooting, this increases the scrollback buffer maximum size from its default 32 kB to 1 MB. Source: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790804/how-to-set-unlimited-scrolling-on-a-tty)